# esri rest service ?f=sitemap returns no services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5

I have some code that queries the esri webserver for a list of services.

I start off with:

https://MyEsriUrl/arcgis/rest/services?f=sitemap

That code worked for years.

We recently attached a portal to our esri webserver.  We're now running v10.5 of both.

Now, the esri admin can issue this command in the browser and it still works, but if I issue it I get an empty list back.

I thought it might be a permissions issue except for three facts:

(1) If I go to https://MyEsriUrl/arcgis/rest/services I can see everything I ought to see.

(2) I've found out that I can now use https://MyEsriUrl/arcgis/rest/services?f=json and that also works correctly.

(3) Esri admin added me to the esri admin role and I still can't see anything with ?f=sitemap.

Obviously, I can rewrite the code to work, but that app is scheduled to be replaced and I would rather spend time working on the replacement app...

Any ideas on how to get ?f=sitemap to work properly?

Comment: By "We recently attached a portal to our esri webserver", do you mean ArcGIS Server got federated with the portal?

@  https://MyEsriUrl/arcgis/rest/services, do you have to log in to see the services? 

Fact 3 in your submission sounds like a browser cache problem. Is it the same from Incognito window?

Comment: Yes, they were federated.  (I didn't do that installation so I had to double check on the terms in order to answer your question.)

I don't have to log into https://MyEsriUrl/arcgis/rest/services by hand, it's happening automatically via active directory.

Good call on #3, I now get data.  

I'll check to see if the ?f=json works once admin is taken away once our gis administrator gets in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this today. If ArcGIS Server is Federated with Portal and there's no service Shared with "***EVERYONE***", services?f=sitemap will list no services because they are locked down. Federating ArcGIS Server with Portal hands over the security of ArcGIS Server to Portal. So, to get f=sitemap to list the services, they need to be shared with "***EVERYONE***".

Comment: Beat me to it!  I just found a reference in some docs that said this is the intended behavior.

However, the ?f=json still appears to work even without admin privs, so I can get the same info with recursive calls to the webserver.   

Don't know what they were thinking...

Comment: Good to see all is well now!

Comment: I've rewritten my code to make multiple calls to the server and it's slow as all get out.   Yuck!

So, I'm going to create a service acct with GIS admin privs and create a web service to wrap the call to the ?f=sitemap option.   That way, the web service will ask as an admin and pass the data I need back much faster.

For gis websites that aren't "ours" (so we don't have admin access), we'll use the new code I've written.

.